# uwp - WebAuthenticationBroker does not show cloudflare captcha

Tags: c#, uwp, recaptcha

I have recently added cloudflare captcha to my website. I am using uwp WebAuthenticationBroker to perform oauth2 like this:

```
  WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(
                                                WebAuthenticationOptions.None,
                                                startUri,
                                                endUri);
```

The problem is that when I get to the login page I do not see the cloudflare captcha checkbox and I think this is why my login fails. When I go to the login page via the web browser I see the cloudflare captcha.

Comment: You could try to check the logs like mentioned here: [debug the WebAuthenticationBroker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker#debugging) to see if there is an error during the process.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT There is no error reported, however on one log I get 

AuthHost disallowed UrlAction: 0x2101 for URL: <https://challenges.cloudflare.com/turnstile/v0/g/dc6b543c1346/api.js>.

Comment: Have you tried to use other values for [WebAuthenticationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationoptions?view=winrt-22621)?

Comment: Please note when using `WebAuthenticationOptions.UseCorporateNetwork`, you need to  enable `privateNetworkClientServer`, `enterpriseAuthentication`, and `sharedUserCertificate` capabilities in your manifest